# How can job-board resume show my preference for long-term jobs?

Tags: resume, job-search

This is related to [How to handle numerous temporary positions in a resume or application form](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/60840/how-to-handle-numerous-temporary-positions-in-a-resume-or-application-form). I'm not worried how it looks to have many short-term contracting jobs; that's the nature of technical writing.

But sometimes recruiters who've seen my resume will call and ask me if I'd be "open" to a permanent (or long-term contract) job.  I tell them the truth: I would **much** prefer it.

I wonder how many recruiters see my resume, assume that I *prefer* contracting, and call someone else.

Is there something I can say in my resume that explains that I'd prefer long-term jobs? Or, at least, that I'm open to both? What's the best way to word it?

EDIT: When I send my resume, I can indeed state my preference in my cover letter. But my question wasn't clear: what about recruiters who see my resume on a job site, and decide whether or not to call **me**?   There's usually no cover letter involved; they do a search for skills or experience, my resume comes up, and they scan it very quickly. In those first few seconds I have to convince them that the rest of my resume is not what I want to do going forward.

Comment: Seeking long-term position.

Comment: @keshlam yep, four words says it all

Comment: Your resume doesn't - your cover letter would.

Comment: @HorusKol That's true, but a lot of recruiters get my resumes from the job boards where there's no cover letter posted.

Comment: @keshlam I hate to be contrary, but wouldn't that rule out short-term positions? Should I say "Seeking both long-term and short-term positions"?

Comment: Ok, "prefer" rather than "seeking". Just say what you mean, as long as it's clear.

Comment: Hmm - how do these job boards work ? I've never used them as recruiter or jobseeker. Is there some space for a statement of intent? I guess a short paragraph at the top of your resume would be okay in this situation.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson, when the recruiter contacts you, you have a meeting and tell them your preference. Why wouldn't that work?

Comment: @JBKing like he said, he's afraid that the recruiters might not contact him, because they incorrectly assume his preference to be for short-term contracts

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Agreed, job boards are probably the only place where I'd recommend use of an Objective statement because you typical don't have a cover letter there. @ OP: consider rewording this question because as-written the answer is "It can't / shouldn't."

Answer (score 3):

This should be addressed in your covering letter. Perhaps explain that although you previously have worked as a contractor or part-time, that you are presently seeking a full time/long term position.

Answer (score 3):

Many job sites have a space for free form text - I'd put it there.

In Linked In, I'd put it in the Summary.

As job sites can vary, you may want to dig around at other candidates & opportunities and see if it's a good plan to mark any checkboxes as yes/no - I'd generally say, go for the widest set of fixed criteria (checkboxes, selected options, etc) that you are actually willing to consider when you are actively hunting.  And then go with a more selective set of criteria more approximating a position preferred to you own when you currently have a job that is acceptable.